# json_encode "not working" properly?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Of course, the subject is sort of tricky... I assume json_encode php function works perfectly.

But there must be something wrong on what I am doing.

I have a variable in my PHP program that actually contains data. Sort of structured data, as it is an object variable with all its attributes set properly.

But, magically, when I apply json_encode to that variable, it just doesn't "fills" the json object.

See the case below:

1. As you can see... the variable $test contains data.

[image]

2. Now, putting the focus on the whole json_encoder($test) thing, it just doesn't fills the "test" {} part of the json object.
   [image]

It's definitely me doing something wrong. But... what?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Pedro

Comment: Are the properties `protected` or `private`?

Comment: `json_encode` works if you want to encode an array into JSON, not objects.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß I can `json_encode` objects fine in php 5.2, provided the properties are `public`. `json_decode` also defaults to decoding into objects instead of arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json_encode` only works with public properties, it cannot take the private or protected attributes of an object and form a JSON representation without any help.

To serialize an object with **all** of its properties, you need to manually implement a function to do so. The official PHP documentation has a good example on how to do this [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#96248)

Comment: Please write your answers in English. It benefits the most amount of people by doing so.

Comment: Consider translating your answer to english. Not everyone can speak spanish.

Comment: Thank you so much. For both responses English and Spanish ;)